# Android: Out of Memory Exception in tablet Honey comb

Tags: android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have one view flipper having 24 children (flash cards), which are given animation. But I am getting Force Close (out of memory exception). I have already tried getApplicationContext() to remove any memory leaks or improving GC. But still I am getting that error. However the same code is working with less than 16 children (flash cards). Total size of .apk is around 48 MB. 24 children .apk is working fine in Samsung 10.1 tablet, while Motorola Xoom tablet is giving Force Close.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little vague, we can't really know from your description what the cause is. But I can assure you it's code related. Try to track down memory allocations with the 'Allocation Tracker' in the DDMS tools in Eclipse. And report back with some more detail or the memory hungry piece of code...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have used DDMS to find out memory hungry objects and also updated my code to have better memory management for graphics, which has solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Eclipse Memory Analyser (MAT) to work out what is using up your memory.  Here's a tutorial - http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html